# Setting up background work item using MoQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am new to unit testing and I am having some difficulties with unit testing background workers.

### Method being tested

```
[HandleExceptions(LoggerName)]
public override IHttpActionResult ValidateToken(string auth_token)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var userInfo = this._userInfoService.CreateUserInfoModel(auth_token);

    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    if (userInfo.Status.IsSuccess)
    {
        //-- I want to test if the following worker is calling RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow method exactly once.
        _taskScheduler.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(task => 
            this._playerDetailsService.RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow(userInfo.UserID, userInfo.ServerID));

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }

    response.Content = new StringContent(_userInfoService.ParseUserInfo(userInfo));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    return this.ResponseMessage(response);
 }
```

### Test method

```
[Test]
public void TestValidateToken_Should_Call_PlayerDetailsService_RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow_Exactly_Once()
{
    // Arrange
    var userInfoModel = AdminControllerHelpers.CreateUserInfoModel();
    userInfoModel.Status = ETIStatus.CreateSuccess();
    _mockUserInfoService
        .Setup(m => m.CreateUserInfoModel(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(userInfoModel);
    _mockUserInfoService
        .Setup(s => s.ParseUserInfo(userInfoModel))
        .Returns(_randomString);
    _mockPlayerService
        .Setup(m => m.RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow(userInfoModel.UserID, userInfoModel.ServerID));
    //-- this is where I got the error.
    _mockTaskScheduler
        .Setup(t => t.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(
            obj => _mockPlayerService.Object.RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow(userInfoModel.UserID,
                userInfoModel.ServerID)));

    // Act
    _controller.ValidateToken(It.IsAny<string>());

    // Assert
    _mockPlayerService
        .Verify(m => m.RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow(userInfoModel.UserID, userInfoModel.ServerID), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

Even though I am setting up everything correctly (at least to me) I get following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: **Argument types do not match**

### Task Scheduler interface which I am mocking

```
public interface ITaskScheduler
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="workItem"> A unit of execution.</param>
    void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the setup to expect an action and then use the callback to execute the mock

```
_mockTaskScheduler
    .Setup(_ => _.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(It.IsAny<Action<CanellationToken>>()))
    .Callback((Action<CancellationToken> action) => action(CancellationToken.None));
```

Also when exercising the method under test, no need to use `It.IsAny<>()`. Just pass a value.

```
// Act
_controller.ValidateToken(String.Empty);

// Assert
_mockPlayerService
    .Verify(m => m.RunPlayerDetailsWorkflow(userInfoModel.UserID, userInfoModel.ServerID), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Should be able to exercise the test as expected now.